# About a boolean function error

Tags: python, function, boolean

In the exercise:
"The squirrels in Palo Alto spend most of the day playing. In particular, they play if the temperature is between 60 and 90 (inclusive). Unless it is summer, then the upper limit is 100 instead of 90. Given an int temperature and a boolean is_summer, return True if the squirrels play and False otherwise."

```
def squirrel_play(temp, is_summer):
  for temp in range(61,101) and is_summer = True: 
    return True
  elif is_summer = False and temp > 90:
    return False
  else:
    return True
```

Or this one:

```
def squirrel_play(temp, is_summer):
  if is_summer = True and temp is in range(61,101):   #Changed
    return True
  elif is_summer = False and temp > 90:
    return False
  else:
    return True
```

I suspect it won't account for every kind of input given, specially because of the last 2 lines, but when I try to run this code, it gives me an error message on the second line. I don't know what it is and I haven't seen any solution for it.

Comment: `is_summer = False` -> `is_summer == False` and `is_summer = True` -> `is_summer == True`, you want comparison, not assignment. Or just use `not is_summer` and `is_summer` you don't need to explicitly compare Booleans to `True` or `False`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't have to test against True or False.  you can just check with `if` or `if not`

```
def squirrel_play(temp, is_summer):
    low_temp = 60
    hi_temp = 91
    if is_summer:        # implicit check for True
        hi_temp = 101
    if temp in range(low_temp, hi_temp):
        return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

first one has a for statement so its definitely wrong.
second one is also wrong because if `is_summer` is False and temperature less that 60 then it will resort to the else block and give out `True` which is wrong

```
def squirrel_play(temp, is_summer):
  if is_summer == True and temp in range(60,101):
    return True
  elif is_summer == False and temp in range(60, 91):
    return True
  else:
    return False
```

Comment: This would give "False" given the input "squirrel_play(60, False)", and the correct answer is True, thank you anyways.

Comment: ah! inclusivity of the first arg! but I think you get the gist

Answer (score 0):

```
def squirrel_play(temp, is_summer):
    if is_summer:
        return 60 <= temp <= 100
    elif not is_summer:
        return 60 <= temp <= 90
    return False
```

Comment: `is_summer` is boolean. So the `elif` is not necessary (it can just be `else`) and the last `return` will never happen...

Answer (score 0):

A more succint version:

```
def squirrel_play(temp, is_summer):
    return temp in range(60, 101 if is_summer else 91)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def squirrel_play(temp, is_summer):
  if is_summer:
    return temp in range(60,101)
  else:
    return temp in range(60,91)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).